# Drools Planner rule only fired once

Tags: java, drools, drools-planner

I have a rule of the form

```
rule "notBar"
    when
        $foo : Foo(bar == false)
    then
        insertLogical(new IntConstraintOccurrence("notBar", ConstraintType.NEGATIVE_SOFT,
                $foo));
end
```

I expect to see this fired once for every Foo with bar being false however the rule is only fired once. Confusingly if I change the `$foo : Foo(bar == false)` to `$foo : Foo()` then it is correctly fired for all Foo's.
What am I missing?

Comment: And you're sure that there are several Foo's with false bars? I don't see any problems with this rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bah. I'm an idiot. My cloneSolution method was calling a copy constructor which didn't correctly copy bar.

Comment: if `foo` is a planning entity (= changes during planning, for example a RoomAssignment) it should be deep cloned, but if `bar` is just a planning fact (= does not change during planning, for example a Room) there's no need to clone it, you can just copy the reference. Although in this case bar is a boolean, so that's just a copy of the value too.

See any of the Drools Planner examples. Btw, What kind of planning problem are you solving?

Comment: @Geoffrey De Smet foo does change but I hadn't thought that I could just copy the reference of facts, think there's a bit of code which does this so can fix that. Just a little bin packing program to help me learn Drools (specifically planner).